# Why am I getting a const reference when I for(auto& it : myUnorderedMap) {... = std::move(it.second)}?

Tags: c++, constants, move, auto, stdmove

Minimally reproducible example [cpp.sh/2nlzz](http://cpp.sh/2nlzz) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  struct Movable {
    Movable() = default;
    Movable ( Movable && ) = default; // move constructor
    vector<int> payload;
  };
  unordered_map<int, Movable> map;
  vector<Movable> target(10);
  int i = 0; 
  for(auto& it : map) {
    target[i] = move(it.second);
    ++i;
  }
}
```

gives me

```
19:15: error: use of deleted function 'main()::Movable& main()::Movable::operator=(const main()::Movable&)'
10:10: note: 'main()::Movable& main()::Movable::operator=(const main()::Movable&)' is implicitly declared as deleted because 'main()::Movable' declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
```

I did define a move constructor for `Movable` and want it to be only moved, never copied, so it's fine that it's not using the regular assignment operator, which I guess it tries to use because `it.second` returns a `const Movable  &` rather than a `Movable  &`, but why so?

I understand that `it.first` has to be const, since keys must not be messed with, but it should be fine to move from the values.

Why do I get a const reference here and how can I fix the code so that I can move?

Comment: You cannot reasonably expect to be able to `move` from a `const` thing.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, I think OP is asking _why_ it's `const`

Comment: Can we get a [mre]?

Comment: @Jesper Juhl ChrisMM is correct. I understand that I can't move from const. I don't understand why I'm getting const there though.

Comment: "*I did define a move constructor for PlaneWithPoints and want it to be only moved, never copied*" - but, did you also implement a move assignment operator as well? The error message would suggest you did not. You are trying to perform a move assignment, but the compiler is choosing to use a copy assignment operator (even though it is deleted), which means there is no move assignment operator available. There is nothing in the code or the error message that suggests this is an issue with `const` at all.

Comment: If you want something to always be moved and *never* copied, you should declare the copy constructor and copy assignment operators as `= delete`, to make sure copies will never happen.

Comment: @JesperJuhl They are defined as deleted automatically if a user-defined move constructor exists. This is the case here according to the error message.

Comment: I added a minimal reproducible example

Comment: `Movable& operator=(Movable&&) = default;` would help.

Comment: @Reny Lebeau, yes I defined a (default) move constructor. Since the thing I access is const, it's clear that I can't move from (so it makes sense that it tries to use the assignment operator instead). But why is it.second const?

Comment: @user1282931, you need a move assignment, not move constructor. Also, `it.second` isn't actually `const`, you're making an incorrect assumption based on the error.

Comment: @Eljay that's it! I was under the wrong assumption it would use the move constructor. obviously these are two different things :)

Comment: @walnut It never hurts to be explicit. 

Comment: You need to define move assignment operator `Movable& operator=( Movable && ) = default;`

Comment: @user1282931 "*yes I defined a (default) move constructor*' - that is not what I asked. Defining a **move assignment operator** is separate from defining a **move constructor**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`it.second` is not `const`.

The issue is that user-declaring the move constructor not only deletes the implicitly-declared copy constructor and copy assignment operator, but also inhibits the implicit declaration of the move assignment operator.

Therefore your class has no move assignment operator and the copy assignment operator is deleted, resulting in the error you are seeing when trying to assign `it.second` to another `Movable`.

```
target[i] = move(it.second);
```

is an assignment expression, not a variable definition or other initialization of an object that would call a constructor.

Add

```
Movable& operator=(Movable&&) = default;
```

to your class and the move assignment will be possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you default the move constructor, you may want to default the move assignment operator yourself, too. Otherwise it would call into the copy assignment operator (which is deleted). A move assignment operator is not generated by the compiler for you in this case.

```
Movable& operator=( Movable && ) = default; // move assignment
```